# Package info of installing app

Tags: android

This looks like a silly question but is it possible to get info of app that is currently downloading, installing or un-installing.

Amongst the info I need App name and Icon.
Form the resources online it looks like you can get the UID of app, but I am not sure of getting these details.

Thanks

Comment: you can get the package name, permission list , api level support, name and icon. do you want this things or anything else(specific) you want ?

Comment: These only but at installation / uninstallation time

Comment: just want to know that why you need that at installation / uninstallation time ?.

Comment: I am working on a launcher and client wants to show the app currently uninstalling or installing.